# C# nunit assertion error: expect and was are the same

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I am using nunit testing  v2.6.4 on visual studios and I have come across a weird bug. The bug happens on "Assert.AreEqual" when it is called on two separate objects(but of the same type), ObjOne  and ObjTwo.

How these two objects are created:

*ObjOne is created with valid fields (firstName = "Foo", lastName = "Bar")

*ObjOne's attributes are serialized and stored.

*ObjOne's attributes are desearialized and put into ObjTwo.

*ObjOne and ObjTwo have the same values for their fields.

However when "Assert.AreEqual" is called on these two objects, it returns back following error

"

```
An exception of type 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' occurred in nunit.framework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:   Expected: <NameSpace.TypeOfObjOneAndTwo>

  But was:  <NameSpace.TypeOfObjOneAndTwo>
```

"

I have Three questions.

1. Is Assert.AreEqual checking to see if the references are the same? Or the values are the same? (The 3.0 documentation, [here](http://nunit.org/docs/2.2/comparisonAsserts.html),  says that it checks the values not the reference, but I am unsure for this version of nunit. Which I couldn't find documentation for). I can not upgrade the version of nunit because of other factors.
2. Does Assert.AreEqual check other values than the public fields of the two objects?
3. Is there anyway for me to get more information on this error?

Comment: It simply calls `Equals` on the objects.  If you don't have it overridden in the class it's going to do reference equality.

Comment: Another option here is to just assert that all the properties of the classes are equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeTest` (after edit `TypeOfObjOneAndTwo`) class must override `bool Equals(object)`. Otherwise there will be no notion of "equal".

Note: `System.ValueType` does override `Equals` which matters if you use a `struct` instead.

You can also override `ToString` if you want better assertion fail messages.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify that "TypeTest" Is the type of ObjOne and ObjTwo. AHHH wait so if I overwrite bool Equals(object) in the class, then Assert.AreEqual will use that one?

Comment: @A.sharif Yes, and don't forget to also override `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue! @Juharr that's an excellent point! I spent some time reading on why you need to also override GetHashCode. However I was confused when I read it and it said that if a class changes (is mutable) then you shouldn't override the GetHashCode. Is this referring to like a Dynamic class? Or is it saying if you change the fields of the class at anytime then don't override the GetHashCode? . Also I can upvote if you add an answer to this question.

Here is the link I was reading http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/692/overriding-equals-in-c-part-2/

Comment: @A.sharif You don't want to override `GetHashCode` for a mutable class because mutating the object (changing the values of the properties that are used to create the hash code) will cause the hash code to change.  This is an issue when storing objects in data structures that use the hash code to index them, thus throwing it off if it changes after it's put into the data structure.

Comment: @juharr I would imagine most classes would have "changing values of properties" in testing. So would that just mean I shouldn't override the GetHashCode in my case?

Comment: @A.sharif It's not hard to make a class immutable.  You just change anything that would mutate a value to instead return a new instance of the class.  That's how `string` works and why you have to do `s = s.Substring(0,1);` instead of just `s.Substring(0,1);`.  But it really depends on how you're using your class.

Comment: @A.sharif As soon as you have a need to override `Equals(object)` you __must__ also override `GetHashCode()`. The concern about mutability is relevant (sometimes you can use mutable types as keys if you know you will not mutated them while they are in the dictionary, but it is a bit dangerous). If you think you are not going to need hash codes, but you override `Equals`, I suggest you do `public override bool GetHashCode() { throw new NotSupportedException("We don't have hash codes!"); }` or similar. In that way it will be clear what happens if you accidentally use something that uses hashes.